# After two successful read fgetc() is not working when used with fseek()

Tags: c, file

I am trying to encrypt(simple bit manuplation algorithm) a file, for that I created three different version

1. create new file in the process of encryption or decryption and deletes the old one and renames it
2. encryption or decryption happens on the same file, using two different `File *`, one opening the file in `rb` and another opening the same file in `rb+`.
3. encryption or decryption happens on the same file, only one `FILE*` is used, file opened in `rb+` mode.

First two versions works as expected they don't use fseek(), but I am encountering problem in version3

code for v3:

```
FILE *inputFile= NULL,*outputFile = NULL;

char *inName = "file.txt",*outName;

/* I am using same source file for all three version controlled by #if, so the following assignment is necessary*/
outName = inName;    

inputFile = fopen(inName,"rb+");
if(inputFile == NULL)
{
  perror(inName);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} 

/* I am using same source file for all three version controlled by #if, so the following assignment is necessary*/
outputFile = inputFile;

long int currentLocation;
unsigned char targetChar;
int intChar;
long int offset,temp;

while(currentLocation = ftell(inputFile),(intChar = fgetc(inputFile))!= EOF)
{
   targetChar = intChar;

   /*#if encryption
   encrypt(&targetChar);
   #else
   decrypt(&targetChar);
   #endif // encryption*/

   /* going back in the file to the starting position of currently read character*/

   temp = currentLocation;
   currentLocation = ftell(inputFile);
   offset = temp - currentLocation; // the offset is always -1 throughout the program(gdb) 

   if(fseek(inputFile,offset,SEEK_CUR)==-1)
   {
       perror(outName);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   // writing the encrypted or decrpted character to the file
   if(fputc(targetChar,outputFile) == EOF)
   {
      perror(outName);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}
fclose(inputFile);
fclose(outputFile);
```

for the first two character fgetc() is working properly the its is not reading at all, meanwhile the `currentLocation` is steadily increment.

if the file has following content

`Hello world !!`

output is

`Heelo world !!`

or

`Heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee ...`

the number of `e` depends on how long the program runs, its an infinite loop.

I am using fseek() to move backwards , does this clear `EOF`(causing the infinite loop condition) even though I am doing only backward `fseek()` ? and I checked in debugger the `fgetc()` is not reading more than two characters but the  `currentLocation` is moving in the increment of 1, why fgetc() is not reading more than two characters?

Comment: Can you give us a cleaned-up, compilable version to test?

Comment: regarding the call to fseek():  you already have the current start location in the file in the currentLocation variable, so you could use: if(fseek(inputFile,currentLocation,SEEK_SET)==-1)

Comment: @user3553031: What is a "cleaned-up, compilable version" ? like removing the commented code?

Comment: inputFile and outputFile are both pointing to the same file descriptor in the OS.  Suggest eliminating outputFile variable and always use inputFile for clarity of code

Comment: @sab: I mean a version that I can save to a file, compile, and execute.  And that doesn't contain unused code or comments referring to things that aren't present in the code.

Comment: @user3629249: I thought, since with SEEK_SET it has to move offset from the beginning for bigger files SEEK_CUR might be more efficient. Is my argument valid?

Comment: @user3553031 : [code](http://ideone.com/rEiMB5), I think this will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if(fputc(targetChar,outputFile) == EOF)
   {
      perror(outName);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   fflush(outputFile);//need flush
}
fclose(inputFile);
//fclose(outputFile);//double close!
```

Comment: why fflush() is needed?, in the other versions,which doesn't have fseek() the programs works without fflush(). should the fseek() accompanied with fflush() always?

Comment: @Sab There are a few of the necessary means for the conversion of the case reading and writing of update mode. see [n1256.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) **7.19.5.3 The fopen function 6**